# Case-insensitive find() function in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In MongoDB a collection with person's document's like

```
({
    name:"looklike", 
    gender:"male"
},{
    name:"Cool dude",
    Gender:"Male"
})
```

are present, I'm trying to do `find({gender:gendervalue})` but getting only one as a result,
I'm using mongoose as a driver for MongoDB.Is there any option we can perform case insensitive `find()`

I have used regular expression `/^male/i`, but it is not getting any result.
I have tried `person.find({gender: 'Male' || 'Male'.toLowerCase()})` , no result

I expected to get as

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d036650f2483e291d0346ca"),
    "name" : "looklike",
    "gender" : "male",
    },
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d036650f2483e291d03473e"),
    "name" : "cool dude",
    "gender" : "male",
}
```

Comment: Try with

person.find({gender: {
            $regex: 'male',
            $options: 'i'
        }})

Comment: Glad i could help, please mark it as accepted answer if it helped you, so that others may find it useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below, it should work

```
/^male$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$regex` with `$options : "i"` for case-insensitive.

Try :

```
Person.find({gender : {$regex : "^male$",$options :"i"}})
```

Comment: it is giving total persons details, including female

Comment: oh I see, It gives female as well, I will edit my code to match only `male`